# Why is this value getting added to the end of a my variable?

Tags: ruby, string

Why does the value `<REDACTED>` get added to the end of variable `two` when running `#get_digest`?

Here's what my code looks like:

```
require 'digest'
require 'uri'

class <REDACTED>   
  def request_to_string(args = {})
    encoded_search_query = URI.encode_www_form(args[:<REDACTED>])
    "#{<REDACTED>}#{<REDACTED>}"
  end

  <redacted>
end
```

Every time I run `#<REDACTED>` the value of `two` changes to something it shouldn't be. What seems to be going wrong?

Comment: A "digest" tag, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're modifying the String instance in `args[:request_string]` directly.

Change it to this instead:

```
str = "#{args[:request_string]}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace `request_string: two` with `request_string: two.dup()`.

Ruby passes the variable by reference, so inside of `get_digest`, when you use the `<<` operator, it is modifying the variable in-place.

Comment: Ruby never passes by reference, it is always pass-by-value. `<<` modifies the *object*, not the variable. Variables aren't objects, the only thing you can do with them is dereference them or assign them.

Comment: I find it best to avoid getting technical on questions like these. Typically, in a general sense, the simple difference between 'pass by value' and 'pass by reference' is whether or not you can mutate a function's parameter within the function without modifying the state of what was passed as that parameter, outside of the function. In this case, you can, which is why I referred to it as 'pass by reference'. If the question had dealt more in-depth with the semantics of how Ruby deals with this, a more technical answer would have been appropriate.

Comment: Pass-by-reference vs. pass-by-value is completely irrelevant to this question. The question is about shared mutable state. However, since you brought it up, I felt that I should correct you. There was a question just a couple of hours ago where someone got confused why his method wasn't modifying the reference even though he had read somewhere or otherwise assumed that Ruby was pass-by-reference. And the simple answer is: his method wasn't working, because Ruby *isn't* pass-by-reference. It's pass-by-value. Understanding the difference between a variable and an object, between a reference …

Comment: … and the thing being referenced, is *crucial* to programming, and confusing the two isn't helpful to newbies.